# There's something wrong with my angularJS routing

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a hard time figuring it out. I separated my route-configs into separate files and I don't know what went wrong. Basically, when I put a link on my page that goes to another page in my angular app, it works, but when I copy that url, and load it another tab or browser, it gives me 404. Why is this happening? Here is my code:

This is what my `app-config.js` looks like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .run(appRunner)
        .config(appConfig);

    appRunner.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$route', '$translate']
    appConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$translateProvider', 'LANGUAGES', 'TRANSLATIONS'];

    function appConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider, LANGUAGES, TRANSLATIONS) {

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/404'    
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        console.log('configured shit...')

        configureTranslations() ;

        function configureTranslations() {
            var english = TRANSLATIONS[LANGUAGES.EN];
            var spanish = TRANSLATIONS[LANGUAGES.ES];

            $translateProvider.translations(LANGUAGES.EN, english);
            $translateProvider.translations(LANGUAGES.ES, spanish);

            $translateProvider.preferredLanguage(LANGUAGES.EN);
        }

    }

    function appRunner($rootScope, $route, $translate) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
            setPageTitle();
        });

        function setPageTitle() {
            console.log('current route: ', $route.current)

            $translate($route.current.title).then(function(pageTitle) {
                document.title = pageTitle;    
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

Then I have another file that configures the route in another page:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.views.caesar')
        .config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function routeConfig($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/caesar-cipher', {
            templateUrl: 'views/caesar-cipher/view.html',
            controller: 'CaesarCipherCtrl as caesarCipherCtrl',
            title: 'CAESAR.TITLE'
            }
        });

    }

})();
```

In my header, I have a link that goes to `/caesar-cipher` page.

```
<a href="/" translate>CAESAR.TITLE</a>
```

As I said when I click on the link, it goes to the correct page. But when I open the same link on another tab, it just gives me 404 and a blank page. How can I resolve this?

It's so strange because the log says, it found the resource, and the next
thing I know, it doesn't find anything.

```
[Fri May 26 2017 02:16:58 GMT+0800 (PHT)] "GET /partials/header/header.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[Fri May 26 2017 02:16:58 GMT+0800 (PHT)] "GET /views/caesar-cipher/view.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[Fri May 26 2017 02:16:58 GMT+0800 (PHT)] "GET /images/ciphers_cover.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[Fri May 26 2017 02:17:00 GMT+0800 (PHT)] "GET /about" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[Fri May 26 2017 02:17:00 GMT+0800 (PHT)] "GET /about" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Comment: Have you made necessary changes in your server when the angular app is configured to work with `html5Mode(true)`?

Comment: I haven't yet. I should research more about that.